# OCLint generate html report error

Tags: oclint

I'm trying to generate an html report from `OCLint` analysis. I've installed `xctool` and generate the `json` file with this command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace SecondHand.xcworkspace  -scheme SecondHand -sdk iphonesimulator  build | tee xcodebuild.log | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json
```

The OCLint scrips has a report-type parameter, so i can create an html report with this command:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -- -max-priority-1 10000 -max-priority-2 10000 -max-priority-3 10000 -rc LONG_LINE=150 -report-type pmd -o oclint.xml
```

but here error with this command:

```
localhost:SecondHand liyaowei$ oclint-json-compilation-database -- -max-priority-1 10000 -max-priority-2 10000 -max-priority-3 10000 -rc LONG_LINE=150 -report-type pmd -o oclint.xml
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
```

oclint: error: cannot open report output file: `oclint: error: cannot open report output file /Users/liyaowei/Desktop/ffstpcommon_V1.6.0/SecondHand/oclint.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Its late but for those who are referring this question use `-report-type xml`